# Get number of current step in a logic app for loop

Tags: azure, for-loop, azure-logic-apps

I have a for loop within my logic app that has over 1000 things to loop through. Some of the items within the logic app go down a different path and I want to keep track of which items do this by adding the step number and the name of the item to an array.

[image]

So I would want an array at the end that was like `["itemABC", "505"]`. Then when I went to '505' within the for each loop, it would show me that same item. Is this possible in logic apps?

Comment: Can you provide an example of the data that goes through the loop?  Maybe 10 items from that so I can provide a solution that is linked to your data.

Answer (score 0):

> Get number of current step in a logic app for loop

Yes, you can do that by using below **`design`**:

[image]

[image]

To make this work, you need to change the concurrency to 1 (if this is not set, you will get randomly):

[image]

**`Output:`**

[image]

**`CodeView:`**

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "Compose_2": {
                "inputs": "@variables('arvar')",
                "runAfter": {
                    "For_each": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Compose"
            },
            "For_each": {
                "actions": {
                    "Append_to_array_variable": {
                        "inputs": {
                            "name": "arvar",
                            "value": "'[@{items('For_each')},@{variables('incvar')}]'"
                        },
                        "runAfter": {
                            "Increment_variable": [
                                "Succeeded"
                            ]
                        },
                        "type": "AppendToArrayVariable"
                    },
                    "Increment_variable": {
                        "inputs": {
                            "name": "incvar",
                            "value": 1
                        },
                        "runAfter": {},
                        "type": "IncrementVariable"
                    }
                },
                "foreach": "@variables('var')",
                "runAfter": {
                    "Initialize_variable_3": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "runtimeConfiguration": {
                    "concurrency": {
                        "repetitions": 1
                    }
                },
                "type": "Foreach"
            },
            "Initialize_variable": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "var",
                            "type": "array",
                            "value": [
                                "rithwik",
                                "bojja",
                                "Charlie",
                                "David",
                                "kingu",
                                "Frank",
                                "Grace",
                                "pangu",
                                "Chotu",
                                "Julia",
                                "test",
                                "Lily",
                                "mangu",
                                "Nora",
                                "Oliver",
                                "jangu"
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            },
            "Initialize_variable_2": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "incvar",
                            "type": "integer",
                            "value": 0
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Initialize_variable": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            },
            "Initialize_variable_3": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "arvar",
                            "type": "array"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Initialize_variable_2": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {},
        "triggers": {
            "manual": {
                "inputs": {
                    "schema": {}
                },
                "kind": "Http",
                "type": "Request"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {}
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this really detailed answer! This is what I had originally however I unfortunately cant change the concurrency to 1 otherwise my logic app takes over 10 hours to run due to the number of steps. Thank you though!

Comment: AFAIK, there is no other way than this, or try using Integration account with Javascript Inline action.